# Android get string from an Array and create another array

Tags: android

Hi im creating a list that has headers of dates and then content underneath. i have a JSON feed that contains fixtures inside each is an array containing the data for each fixture one string i need is matchdate to create my headers however if i was to just run through it it will create multiple instances of the same match day so id have 3 headers with the same date for example. how can i extract that information and the create another array that says if this date already exists go through the next one and so on. i know it's pretty specific question but if someone could at least point me in the right direction. thanks in advance.

heres my feed

```
 fixturesArray = [{"awayteam":"Team 1","comp":"LGE","location":null,"attendance":null,"awayscore":null,"division":"Testing 1","homescore":null,"fixture_note":null,"kickoff":"15:30:00","awayteam_id":"64930","matchdate":"2012-07-07","awaypens":null,"homepens":null,"division_id":"5059","hometeam":"Team 3","hometeam_id":"64932"},{"awayteam":"Team 2","comp":"LGE","location":null,"attendance":null,"awayscore":null,"division":"Testing 1","homescore":null,"fixture_note":null,"kickoff":"15:00:00","awayteam_id":"64931","matchdate":"2012-07-07","awaypens":null,"homepens":null,"division_id":"5059","hometeam":"Team 4","hometeam_id":"64933"},{"awayteam":"Team 4","comp":"LGE","location":null,"attendance":null,"awayscore":null,"division":"Testing 1","homescore":null,"fixture_note":null,"kickoff":"15:00:00","awayteam_id":"64933","matchdate":"2012-07-14","awaypens":null,"homepens":null,"division_id":"5059","hometeam":"Team 1","hometeam_id":"64930"}]
```

heres what i have tried so far

```
Log.v("MyFix", "fixturesArray = " + fixturesArray);
       if(fixturesArray.length() < 1){

             TextView emptytext = (TextView) fixturesView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
             emptytext.setText("No Upcoming Fixtures Available");

       }else{
        try{   


            JSONArray datesArray = null;
            fixturesInfo = null;
            String matchDateTemp = "";

            for(int t = 0; t < fixturesArray.length(); t++){
               JSONObject matchDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(t);
               String matchDate = matchDateDict.getString("matchdate");
               JSONArray matchdates = matchdates.put(matchDate);

               Log.v("MyFix", "matchdate = " + matchDate);

               tempArray.put(t, fixturesArray);
               fixturesInfo.put(matchDate, tempArray);

            }

            Log.v("MyFix", "fixturesInfo = " + fixturesInfo);
            Log.v("MyFix", "tempArray = " + tempArray);


        }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the piece of data then iterate through the new arraylist checking for a duplicate before adding.

```
int matchCount=0;                                           // set count of matches to 0
String matchDate = matchDateDict.getString("matchdate");    // get the data to compare
for (int i = 0; i < uniqueDateArrayList.size(); i++){       // set loop to iterate through unique date arraylist
    if (matchDate.equals(uniqueDateArray[i])){              // compare the date to the date stored at position i
        matchCount++;                                       // if it matches increase the match count
    }
}

if (matchCount == 0) {
    uniqueDateArrayList.add(matchDate)                       // if there is no matching date, add it to the unique date arraylist
}
```

That should give you an array list containing all of the unique dates in your data.